How to compile a tools based on WL to C/C++
I am a new comer to learn WL.
I tried to compile a tool named qmritools into c code version.
After searching for some methods like Compile or CCodeGenerate, I found that they generate c code just for some brief and computation-complex operations.
What should I do when trying to compile some functions that nested other functions into C? Like qmritools, when run DixonTools's DixonReconstructfile (https://github.com/mfroeling/QMRITools/blob/master/QMRITools/Kernel/DixonTools.wl#L479),  there are many functions like GenerateAmpsfrom other WL .
Does WL have this kind of Ccode compiler or linker to recursively or automatically compile WL code into C?
Great thanks.

No, I am afraid, such a magical tool does not exist, yet. In principle, Compile can inline other CompiledFunction (use CompilationOptions -> {"InlineCompiledFunctions" -> True}), but the results are typically poor.
